# What does extends mean in a class declaration?

Tags: php, oop, class

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Understanding Classes in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3124818/understanding-classes-in-php)

I pretty often see "extends" in classes, like

```
class a
{
  // its content here
}

class b extends a
{
  //other content here
}
```

What's the job of extends?

Comment: Lots of duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+class+extends

Comment: EboMike: Did I ask you anything? =)

Comment: If only PHP had a widely available, concise, manual....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a OOP principle called [*Inheritance*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_%28object-oriented_programming%29).

When a class `B` inherits (extends) from class `A`, an instance of class `B` inherits all the functionality from class `A` and has access to `protected` (and of course `public`) methods and attributes via [`parent::`](http://php.net/manual/en/keyword.parent.php).

Read more about [inheritance in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/keyword.parent.php).

---

Inheritance is often used when classes *share* certain properties.
For example, I can have a class *Person* that holds information such as `name` and *subclasses* `Customer`, `Partner`, that inherit the property `name` but add some custom functionality.

Answer (score 4):

That's the keyword PHP uses for class inheritance.  `class b` is a sub-class of `class a` and therefore is for all intents and purposes an instance of `class a` but also with the additional (extended) properties defined in `class b`.

Further reading [here](http://php.net/manual/en/keyword.extends.php).

Answer (score 2):

Class inheritance.

In general - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_(object-oriented_programming)

PHP specifics - http://php.net/manual/en/keyword.extends.php

Answer (score 1):

There is a reasonable introduction to class inheritance in the PHP manual:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.inheritance.php